# React Material UI menu items with different background colors - RAL color selector component

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I would like to create component for selecting RAL color using TextField (select option) and MenuItem, I would like to have each item in menu with background color reflecting RAL color it is refering to. Problem is that Material UI does not support inline styling anymore. What is the best way to solve this problem ?

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import MenuItem from '@material-ui/core/MenuItem';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {

  },
}));

const colorDef = [ 
  {
    name: "RAL 1000",
    rgb: "#CCC58F",
  },
  {
    name: "RAL 1001",   
    rgb: "#D1BC8A",
  },
  {
    name: "RAL 1002",       
    rgb: "#D2B773",
  },
]

export default function RALList(props) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [color, setColor] = React.useState(colorDef[1]);

  const handleChange = () => (event) => {
    setColor(event.target.value)
    props.onValueChange(event)
  }

  return (
    <TextField  
      className={classes.root}
      select id="color" label="Kolor" variant="outlined" size="small" 
      value={color.name}
      onChange={handleChange()}
      >
        {colorDef.map((option) => (
          <MenuItem key={option.name} value={option.name} className={{ background: option.rgb}}>
            {option.name}
          </MenuItem>
        ))}
  </TextField>
  );
}

RALList.propTypes = {
  onValueChange: PropTypes.func
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line of your code in each `MenuItem`

from

```
className={{ background: option.rgb }}
```

to

```
style={{ background: option.rgb }}
```